# FileUpload control using Html.BeginForm/Ajax.BeginForm does not work.(htmlfile access is denied in IE).Css style to upload control button

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

To give a CSS style to Upload Control button I created a fakebutton.On click of this fake button i trigger the click event of file upload control.
When i use Jquery ajax it gives me a error **htmlfile access is denied**.
but when i use Html.BeginForm it does not give me error nor does it work.

```
<div id="divUploadForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAction", "HomeController",new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "divUploadForm",        
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace        
    }))
    {  
        <fieldset>                            
                <input type="text" id="fakeupload" name="fakeupload" class="fakeupload" />
                <input type="button" value="Browse" id="BrowseBtn" />
                <input type="file" name="file" id="files-to-upload" onchange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value;" style="display: none" />
                <input type='submit' id='upload-files' value='Save'/>            
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function () {
        $('#BrowseBtn').click(function () {
            $('#files-to-upload').trigger('click');
        });
        $('#fakeupload').click(function () {
            $('#files-to-upload').trigger('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update**  : also used

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAction", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "UploadForm" }))
{
...
}
```

Still it gives the "Error:Access is denied."

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Html.BeginForm` with `AjaxOptions`? There is no such overload. Only `Ajax.*` helpers take `AjaxOptions`.

This being said you cannot upload files with AJAX. So stick with a normal Html.BeginForm but make sure you specify proper `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAction", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to use javascript to upload files and handle things like progress, etc... you may take a look at one of the [numerous](http://www.plupload.com/) [plugins](http://www.uploadify.com/) [available](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Comment: :Thanks.Earlier i did the same thing but it still gives me the "Error: Access is denied."

Comment: @Mangesh Pimpalkar, that might be related to the fact that you are trying to trigger click events on hidden file elements.

Answer (score 1):

if your file upload control is hidden the browsers wont allow click on it for security reasons, plus you cannot use ajax to upload files as javascript cannot access the file contents